# R script, count max values in a row of data

Tags: r, max, summary

I have this chunk of code in an R script, and what it does is that from a data frame (that has say 4 columns) finds and counts for each row the column with the maximal value. But when in a row there are ties (say two or maybe three max values), the code below just considers the first one (does not count the other ones). Is there in R any way to count the columns with max value even when there are multiple max values (ties?) in rows.

```
m_0 <- read.csv(file="Tests/myResults", head=FALSE, sep=",")

varb_m0 <- c(m0$ V4)

#create dataframe
```

> myDataFrame <- data.frame(mode_0=varb_m0)

```
#find max
result <- apply(myDataFrame,1,which.max)

#factor it
result <- factor(result)

#print result
names(myDataFrame)[result]

summary(result)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of `myDataFrame`, perhaps with `dput()`?

Comment: This isn't an example we can reproduce. If you do `dput(myDataFrame)` (or `dput(head(myDataFrame))`) we could.

Comment: Do you mean that you need the myResult file? Sorry I am new to R and I have no idea of what you are talking about

Comment: We don't need the whole file. `dput(head(myDataFrame))` will spit out some R code that anyone can then use to reproduce a chunk of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do it would be to make a function first:

```
all_max <- function(x) {which(x == max(x))}  #Index of each value that is maximum.
```

And then just apply that to your data frame:

```
result <- apply(myDataFrame,1,all_max)
```

I think the rest should be the same, though you didn't provide any data to test it on.

Comment: I am going to try it, but I believe Excel/Libre Calc is easier to use and manage so i am going to try with that. Thanks though :)